# Signifiance of interaction terms in lm()

Tags: r, regression, interaction, linear-model, interpretation

I'm trying to model the relationships between carbon monoxiode, resistance of a sensor, temperature and humidity. Therefore, I use

`m0<- lm(log(Resistance) ~ (log(CO) + rH + T), data = df)`

which results in

```
Call:
lm(formula = log(Resistance) ~ (log(CO) + rH + T), data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.71809 -0.18725 -0.06563  0.17564  0.99559 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    26.046626   1.458346  17.860   <2e-16 ***
log(CO)        -0.429881   0.032594 -13.189   <2e-16 ***
rH             -0.013227   0.001183 -11.180   <2e-16 ***
T              -0.021607   0.002412  -8.959   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3011 on 232 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6144,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6094 
F-statistic: 123.2 on 3 and 232 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

when I try to take into account interaction terms

`m1<- lm(log(Resistance) ~ (log(CO) + rH + T)^3, data = df)`

I receive this:

```
> summary(m1)

Call:
lm(formula = log(Resistance) ~ (log(CO) + rH + T)^3, data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.67817 -0.18349 -0.06939  0.20253  0.86917 

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)             43.8203193 27.6942070   1.582    0.115
log(CO)                 -0.8233499  0.6229791  -1.322    0.188
rH                       0.3187094  0.6756116   0.472    0.638
T                       -0.1504309  0.5718310  -0.263    0.793
log(CO):rH              -0.0076388  0.0151992  -0.503    0.616
log(CO):T                0.0027646  0.0128662   0.215    0.830
rH:T                    -0.0136750  0.0139218  -0.982    0.327
log(CO):rH:T             0.0003113  0.0003133   0.994    0.321

Residual standard error: 0.2955 on 228 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.635, Adjusted R-squared:  0.6238 
F-statistic: 56.66 on 7 and 228 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

with quite different significances for the single terms like `log(CO)` and `T`. This isn't something I would expect?

Comment: Comparing the three standard errors in the smaller model to the interaction model show they are relatively larger in the interaction model. This can be a symptom of multicollinearity,  and hence worth checking for.

Comment: Thanks for that hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is quite normal for the estimates and standard errors (and hence p values) to differ for a variable after it is included in an interaction. This is because, when a variable is *not* included in an interaction, it is interpreted as the estimated change in the response for a 1 unit change in that variable, *keeping all other variables unchanged*. However, when involved in an interaction, the main effect is then the estimated changed in the response for a 1 unit change in that variable, *when the other variable that it is interacted with is zero*. So in your case, in the 2nd model, -0.823 is the estimated change in `log(Resistance)` for a 1 unit increase in `log(CO)` when `rH` is zero and `T` is zero.

Comment: Ok, thank you! How do I actually deal with this? How do I make a decision? What is true? :)

Comment: Make a decision about what ? As for truth, I don't know what you mean, these are very different models with different tests. If you have good theoretical reasons to include those interactions then retain them, but otherwise they don't seem to be heliping. It is often a good idea to consider nonlinear terms as well as (or sometimes instead of) interactions. Again, it should all be driven by the theory. When modelling interaction it is often a good idea to centre the variables so that the main effect are more interpretable (that is, unless values of zero make good sense)

Comment: Thanks for the advices! A suggestion in which way to center the variables?

Comment: Mean centring is often a good place to start.

Comment: Do I center only the explanatory variables (here, Resistance) or also the predictor variables (like temperature, humidity and carbon monoxiode)?

Comment: Since they are all involved in interactions then it will help to centre them all, unless zero is meaningful for these variables in the context of your experiment. A canonical example of where this is helpful is in `height` of subject. If `height` is involved in an interaction then the other other main effect will be interpreted conditional on height being zero which is nonsensical. So it depends on your context. Also you will need to cente log(CO) not CO, obviously. Finally "predictors" and "explanatory variables" have the same meaning.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "outcome" (response) and "explanatory variables" (predictors or regressors) ? You don't need to centre the outcome

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I wonder about the case where a variable = 0 makes sense. In my case it is about applied gas, temperature and so on. Physically, this is possible but has never been done in the experiment. Should I center or not?
True, I mix up all the involved terms all the time. Let's call it independent and dependent variables. Much easier to remember :)

Comment: It's hard to say. Put yourself in the shoes of an expert in your domain who you are explaining the results to. Would they find it odd that you are explaining a coeficient with reference to another variable at zero ? Would it be more natural for it to be the mean ? If so, then centre it ? If not, then don't. If you are not sure then don't.

Comment: That's a good hint. I tend to center it, but I will think over it.